# Playing raw PCM data from a file using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to play raw PCM data from a file (such as rawAudio.raw). I have generated raw data from this code using Naudiodon:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const portAudio = require('naudiodon');

console.log(portAudio.getDevices());

const ai = new portAudio.AudioIO({
  inOptions: {
    channelCount: 2,
    sampleFormat: portAudio.SampleFormat32Bit,
    deviceId: 12,
    sampleRate: 48000,
    closeOnError: true,
  }
});
const ws = fs.createWriteStream('rawAudio.raw');
ai.pipe(ws);
ai.start();

setTimeout(function(){
    ai.quit();
}, 5000)
```

I can play this file normally in Audacity, but I need to do it using Node.js. How do I do that?